# Create mutiple files in multiple directories

Tags: linux, bash, console

I 've got tree of folders like:

```
00 -- 0
   -- 1
   ...
   -- 9
 ...
99 -- 0 
   -- 1
   ...
   -- 9
```

How is the simplest way to create in every single subfolders a file like:
/00/0/00_0.txt
and save to every files some kind of data?

I tried with **touch** and with **loop** but without success.
Any ideas how to make it very simple?

Comment: show us the code you have tried.

Comment: Are the actual folders also digits or did you make a simple example for us (thanks!) ? A rude way is using running through 00-99 and 0-9 and trying to touch the files, ignoring errors. Or show as your loop with somethng like `for dir in */*/; do ..`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List all directories using globs. Modify the listed paths with `sed` so that `37/4` becomes `37/4/37_4.txt`. Use `touch` to create empty files for all modified paths.

```
touch $(printf %s\\n */*/ | sed -E 's|(.*)/(.*)/|&\1_\2.txt|')
```

This works even if `12/3` was just a placeholder and your actual paths are something like `abcdef/123`. However it will fail when your paths contain any special symbols like whitespaces, `*`, or `?`.

To handle arbitrary path names use the following command. It even supports linebreaks in path names.

```
mapfile -td '' a < <(printf %s\\0 */*/ | sed -Ez 's|(.*)/(.*)/|&\1_\2.txt|')
touch "${a[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. First command works. Another question in that area - how can I write the text to all of this files in that order: key00=value0 in all files. key is folder value is subfolder.

Comment: @parsley93 : Did you click on downvote (v) instead of up(^)  of both answers by mistake?

Comment: @KaushikNayak I'm afraid someone else downvoted us on purpose. Parsley93 has not enough reputation to vote. Maybe the downvoter thinks that we shouldn't answer low effort questions to encourage people to ask more low effort question – just a guess. I would be glad to hear the exact reason. Random downvotes can be really frustrating. Have my upvote to compensate for that anonymous downvote.

Comment: As @KaushikNayak said I cannot downnote - I only gave tick for right solution

Comment: Ok. @parsley93 pardon me. Right Socowi, whoever downvoted should give  a valid reason. By the way have one from me as well:-)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `find` and then run commands using `-exec`

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -exec bash -c 'f={};
cmd=$(echo "${f}/${f%/*}_${f##*/}.txt"); touch $cmd' \;
```

the bash substitution `${f%/*}_${f##*/}` replaces the last `/` with `_`

Comment: Your solution also works :)